# Iterate recursively using for loop in windows cmd, excluding node_modules and it's subdirectories

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, npm, eslint

Dear stackoverflow users I am Linux user and I am developing an app with my mates.
They are using Windows and the problem is that in my `package.json` I got linter script which looks like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint '.'"
}
```

The following script works fine on Linux (it lints all the files recursively excluding `node_modules` folder), but it fails on Windows.
I was searching through the web and I found the script which should be used by Windows users.

```
"wlint": "for /r %f in (*.js) do eslint %f"
```

My mates have told me that it works fine on Windows except the fact that it goes through `node_modules` directory.

**Question is:** How to modify script to exclude `node_modules` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command echos the pathname into the pipeline, looks for lines that do not contain the string `\node_modules\`, then runs eslint on them.

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.js) DO (ECHO %~f | (findstr /V /L "\\node_modules\\" >NUL && eslint "%~f"))
```

Something like this should be able to do what you want.

Comment: I'd add the `/I` option to `findstr` to treat the strings case-insensitively, like Windows treats paths...